# How can I remove null values from a postgres jsonb array?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.5

Given a jsonb field with a value of

```
{
  values: [null, 'test', { key: 'value' }]
}
```

is it possible to return an output of

```
{
  values: [ 'test', { key: 'value' }]
}
```

Ive looked at the docs and have found some functions like 
    jsonb_strip_nulls() 
which this only works for keys with null values and 
    array_remove()
which I cannot get to work with jsonb.

I would use

```
UPDATE table 
  SET data = jsonb_set(data, '{values}'::text[], jsonb_agg(elem), false)
FROM data, 
     jsonb_array_elements(data-> 'values') WITH ORDINALITY AS t(elem, nr)
WHERE jsonb_typeof(elem) <> 'null'
GROUP BY (data.id)
```

and this would work correctly for mose cases, but I need it to work with the case:

```
{
  values: [null, null, null]
}
```

the above query does not return

```
{
  values: []
}
```

in this case.

Any help is appriciated!! Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With using `coalesce` you could achieve it like that:

```
WITH    test( data ) AS (
            VALUES
                ( $${"values": [null, "test", { "key": "value" }]}$$::jsonb ),
                ( $${"values": [null, null, null]}$$::jsonb )
        )
SELECT  jsonb_set(
            d.data,
            '{values}',
            coalesce(
                jsonb_agg(t.elem) FILTER ( WHERE NOT (t.elem = 'null') ),
                $$[]$$::jsonb
            ),
            FALSE
        )
FROM    test d,
        jsonb_array_elements( d.data-> 'values') WITH ORDINALITY AS t(elem)
GROUP BY d.data;


               jsonb_set
----------------------------------------
 {"values": ["test", {"key": "value"}]}
 {"values": []}
(2 rows)
```

NOTE: I used `FILTER` instead of `WHERE` check for `null`, but with `coalesce` usage your query should work also.

Comment: I know it is a old post, but for those like me still need a solution for this problem, you can use `json_strip_nulls` available on Postgres 9.5

Comment: @EderF.Freitas No, you cannot. Json_strip_nulls was already menationed by the OP, and it only works for keys in objects, not for arrays.

Answer (score 6):

For PostgreSQL 12:

```
select jsonb_path_query_array('{"values": [null, "test", { "key": "value" }]}', '$.values[*] ? (@ != null)')
```